# How do I extend the margins of my chart so that my legend doesn't get cut off?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I want to display a legend for my bar chart in dc.js, but I want to display it outside of the chart (including the axis). However, the text is always cut off. And when I change the margins, the axis label gets extended and the styling is off. How would I go about extending the margins only for the legend and not for the axis label or chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really difficult that I've tried before answering you. Give your bar chart's canvas a bigger size than the 'width' of your chart. Now mention the `x( )` and `y( )` coordinates in the legend to be greater than the chart's width. That's it.

In my case, my chart's `svg` or "canvas" is given the full width of the page, but I allowed chart's*(note that the chart is half the width of the canvas where the chart is rendered)* width to be only half(say calcWidth = 550). Now I've written "legend" as

```
.width(calcWidth)
.legend(dc.legend().x(width+250).y(5).itemHeight(15).gap(5))
```